# blender 2.7 gesture inputs are discontinued?

Tags: customization

I use wacom and searching for gesture input methods blender used to have. Please let me know where the option is?

Answer (score 1):

Gesture Ops add on let you customize your mouse gesture to execute any operator in Blender.

BTW, I am the creator of this add-on.

[You can download it here](https://gumroad.com/l/gesture-ops)